# MATLAB vectorize

Tags: matlab, vectorization

I was wondering if anyone could help me vectorize this piece of code.

fr_bw is a matrix.

```
 for i=1:height
   for j=1:width      
                [min_w, min_w_index] = min(w(i,j,:));  
                mean(i,j,min_w_index) = double(fr_bw(i,j));
                sd(i,j,min_w_index) = sd_init;
     end
end
```

Comment: Is fr_bw a matrix or function?

Comment: Sorry I was meant to add that. Yes fr_bw is a matrix.

Comment: Will the person who "-1"d this question please explain? It is a reasonable question.

Answer (score 1):

I can't help you with this `sif (match == 0)` stuff -- if it's supposed to be `if (match == 0)` you're not changing `match` so it could be brought outside the loop.

Otherwise, how about this:

```
[min_w, min_w_index] = min(w, [], 3);
r = repmat((1:height)',1,width);
c = repmat(1:width,height,1);
ind = sub2ind(size(w),r(:),c(:),min_w_index(:));
w_mean(ind) = double(fr_bw);
w_sd(ind) = repmat(sd_init,height,width);
```

(Please note that `mean` is a built-in function so I renamed your variables to `w_mean` and `w_sd`.)

The `sub2ind` call gives you linear indices that correspond to subscripts. (Direct subscripts won't work; `z([a1 a2 a3],[b1 b2 b3],[c1 c2 c3])` refers to 27 elements in the `z` array with subscripts that are the cartesian product of the specified subscripts, rather than `z(a1,b1,c1)` and `z(a2,b2,c2)` and `z(a3,b3,c3)` that you might expect.)

Here's an illustration of this technique:

```
>> height = 6; width = 4;
>> w = randi(1000,height,width,2)

w(:,:,1) =

   426   599    69   719
   313   471   320   969
   162   696   531   532
   179   700   655   326
   423   639   408   106
    95    34   820   611


w(:,:,2) =

   779   441   638   696
   424   528   958    68
    91   458   241   255
   267   876   677   225
   154   519   290   668
   282   944   672   845

>> [min_w, min_w_index] = min(w, [], 3);
>> min_w_index

min_w_index =

     1     2     1     2
     1     1     1     2
     2     2     2     2
     1     1     1     2
     2     2     2     1
     1     1     2     1

>> z = zeros(height,width,2);
>> r = repmat((1:height)',1,width);
>> c = repmat(1:width,height,1);
>> ind = sub2ind(size(w),r(:),c(:),min_w_index(:));
>> z(ind) = 1

z(:,:,1) =

     1     0     1     0
     1     1     1     0
     0     0     0     0
     1     1     1     0
     0     0     0     1
     1     1     0     1


z(:,:,2) =

     0     1     0     1
     0     0     0     1
     1     1     1     1
     0     0     0     1
     1     1     1     0
     0     0     1     0
```

Comment: I have removed the if statement.

Comment: @Richie Thank you for your answer this does not seem to work as well as the for loop, I am unsure why, but the code seems to produce better performance but does not produce the correct results, could you see any reason why?

Comment: without more context / information about what you're expecting, we can't diagnose the problems you are having.

Comment: There seems to be values left in the w_mean that should not be there after a few runs of the code. So what I mean is this piece of code is ran multiple times and does not seem to update correctly this dosent seem to happen using the for loop, does that help it is hard to explain?

Comment: Unless you have example data that I can use, I can't reproduce it on my end.

Answer (score 0):

A few comments on your code:

1. Did you mean `if` rather than `sif`?
2. The code isn't replicable at the moment, since you haven't provided examples of the variables `w`, `fr_bw` and `sd_init`.  This makes it tricky to give an exact answer.
3. It looks like you are assigning things to a variable named `mean`.  This will shadow the `mean` function, and probably cause you grief.
4. I'm just guessing, but I don't think `double` does what you think it does.  You don't need to convert individual elements of a numeric matrix to type `double`; they are already the correct type.  (On the other hand, if `fr_bw` is a different type, say integers, then you should create a new variable `dbl_fr_bw = double(fr_bw);` before the loops.

You might need to adjust the dimension over which you calculate the minimums, but the first line of the loop can be replaced with

```
[min_w, min_w_index] = min(w, [], 3)
```

<del>The second line with</del>

```
mean_values(:, :, min_w_index) = double(fr_bw)
```

Not sure about the third line, since I don't know what `sd_init` is/does.

Comment: Your second line suggestion will **not** work. Try it. You'll get an error.

Comment: namely, subscript indices are independent and do not work with a matrix of values. Unless all the min_w_index values are the same, it refers to indices that are all the rows and columns and the union of all the min_w_index values. This is a 3-dimensional slice of mean_values and MATLAB expects the right-hand-side to be a 3-D matrix of the right size.

Comment: @Jason S: Good catch; offending line removed.  Will defer to your answer.

Comment: I could have sworn there was a way to do what you suggest (it was my first approach too, until it didn't work), but aside from logical addressing, I'm not aware of anything.

Comment: @Jason,  @Richie Thank you for your answer this does not seem to work as well as the for loop, I am unsure why, but the code seems to produce better performance but does not produce the correct results, could you see any reason why?